# Sha1 vba binary

Tags: excel, hash, binary, sha1, vba

I found what in VBA i can use `http://vb.wikia.com/wiki/SHA-1.bas` to convert string to SHA1, problem is what it convert HEX values but i need Binary.

How to change this script so it work with binary values?